# How to require 2FA for local Ubuntu login?

Tags: server, login, security, two-factor-authentication

There are [directions on configuring 2FA for SSH](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/configure-ssh-2fa). However, I'm interested in mandating 2FA for logal sign in. For example, normally, the login might look like this:

```
ubuntu login: cocomac
Password:
```

However, I'd like it to prompt me for a (valid) 2FA code after entering my password for additional security[1].

I'm specifically interested in Ubuntu Server, although Ubuntu Desktop (any flavor) answers are acceptable. Any supported (non-EOL) version is fine.

How can I add 2FA for local sign ins on Ubuntu?

---

[1] For sake of the question, assume physical security of the system isn't an issue.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install the `Google PAM` package through the terminal. `PAM`, an abbreviation for `Pluggable Authentication Module`, is a mechanism that provides an extra layer of authentication on the Linux platform.

   ```
   sudo apt install libpam-google-authenticator
   ```

   When prompted, hit 'Y' and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to continue with the installation.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install libpam-google-authenticator
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
libqrencode3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libpam-google-authenticator libqrencode3
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 120 not upgraded.
Need to get 56.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 183 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
```

2. Install the [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&pli=1) app on your tablet or smartphone. It will give you a 2FA code that will refresh every 30 seconds.

[image: Google authenticator]

3. When we have installed Google Authenticator, we can go on and configure the Google PAM package on Ubuntu by modifying the /etc/pam.d/common-auth file as shown.

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/pam.d/common-auth
   ```

   Append the line below to the file as indicated.

   ```
   auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
   ```

```
3 #
4 # This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
5 # and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
6 # the central authentication scheme for use on the system
7 # (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.). The default is to use the
8 # traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
9 #
10 # As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
11 # To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
12 # local modules either before or after the default block, and use
13 # pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules. See
14 # pam-auth-update(8) for details.
15

16 auth required pam_google_authenticator.so # Add this to the file

17
18 # here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
19 auth [success=1 default=ignore]
20 # here's the fallback if no module succeeds
21 auth requisite
pam_unix.so nullok_secure
pam_deny.so
22 # prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
```

Save the file and exit.

Now, run the command below to initialize PAM.

```
google-authenticator
```

Type 'Y' when asked if you want time based tokens:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ google-authenticator

Do you want authentication tokens to be time-based (y/n) y
```

Next, a QR code will be displayed on the terminal and also some information will be displayed. The information displayed includes:

- Secret key
- Verification code
- Emergency scratch codes

You need to save this information to a vault for future reference.

On your phone, enter the `Google Authentictor` app and create a new 2FA Account. Then select scan QR code and scan the QR code that is portrayed in the terminal (*Note: you might need to maximize the terminal to see the whole thing*).

```
Your new secret key is: IFERMENW4I4ACQGU5A4IMEWRZY
Your verification code is 300435
Your emergency scratch codes are:
55056039
74301730
41124860
44081953
35754525
Do you want me to update your "/home/user/.google_authenticator" file? (y/n)
```

5. Thereafter, Select 'y' to update the Google authenticator file in your home folder.

   In the next prompt, restrict login to just one log in every 30 seconds in order to prevent attacks that might arise due to man-in-the-middle attacks. So select 'y'

```
Your new secret key is: IFERMENW414ACQGU5A4IMEWRZY Your verification code is 300435
Your emergency scratch codes are:
55056039
74301730
41124860
44081953
35754525
Do you want me to update your "/home/user/.google_authenticator" file? (y/n) y
Do you want to disallow multiple uses of the same authentication
token? This restricts you to one login about every 30s, but it increases your chances to notice or even prevent man-in-the-middle attacks (y/n) y
```

In the next prompt, hit 'n' to disallow the extension of the time duration which addresses time-skew between server and client. This is just an option to make your 2FA more secure.

Lastly, set the rate for incorrect login attempts to 3.

```
By default, a new token is generated every 30 seconds by the mobile app. In order to compensate for possible time-skew between the client and the server, we allow an extra token before and after the current time. This allows for a time skew of up to 30 seconds between authentication server and client. If you experience problems with poor time synchronization, you can increase the window from its default size of 3 permitted codes (one previous code, the current code, the next code) to 17 permitted codes (the 8 previous codes, the current code, and the 8 next codes). This will permit for a time skew of up to 4 minutes between client and server.
Do you want to do so? (y/n) n
If the computer that you are logging into isn't hardened against brute-force login attempts, you can enable rate-limiting for the authentication module. By default, this limits attackers to no more than 3 login attempts every 30s. Do you want to enable rate-limiting? (y/n) y.
user@ubuntu:~$
```

At this point, 2FA is enabled on your machine. Now any command with `sudo` will require the code that can be found in the Google Authenticator app.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update Verification code:
[sudo] password for tecmint:
Hit: 1 http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.ke/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.ke/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB] 
Get:3 http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.ke/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Get:4 http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.ke/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB] 
Get:5 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease [11.0 kB] Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Get:8 http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.ke/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,88 5 kB]
```

Reboot and at the login screen you will be prompted for your 2FA code.

*Source: https://www.tecmint.com/enable-two-factor-authentication-in-ubuntu/*

Comment: (a) Please don't post screenshots of text, copy paste the text here and use code formatting instead. (b) I don't think that site permits you to copy-paste its content wholesale here.

Comment: @muru I have changed my answer. Thanks for helping me make my posts better.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in a lot of different ways.

For examples you can

1. have a luks encrypted hard drive and remove the luks-header into a usb drive
2. use a luks encrypted partition with yubikey
3. add a password to grub
4. what was suggested above..

I am sure theres a lot of other ways.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).